# No "create tag wiki" button on meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I wanted to edit the [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) tag, and [the page](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tags/info) said I should:

> Click the button below to get started.

I don't see any button to click, even when I scroll down:

[image: Screenshot of the tags tag info page]

Comment: I see you just suggested edits for the [tag:tagging] tag on the main site. I had to reject them because they were specifically about tagging on the SE site, which would have only been appropriate on the meta. On the main site the tagging tag is about tagging on unix, for example mp3 meta info or picture managers that tag photos.

Comment: Ah yes. I should go to sleep, now. But you should have used it to make an tag-tag on meta! :)

Comment: I can't, I'm not a moderator either! The meta-site tags might even be SE staff only, I don't know.

Comment: Therefore you don't have this black diamond! Work harder! Get elected!

Comment: If I work much harder on SE I will go hungry for lack of real work. Also I don't think it's matter of work so much of as getting elected, but there aren't current elections so that's irrelevant as well.

Comment: @Jeff Not being able to edit tag wikis is by design, but there is a genuine UI bug (or maybe two bugs, one for <20k and one for >20k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are right; [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites) on the main meta explains that tag wikis are copied from the main meta and can't be edited by anyone (even mods). However, the tagging tag on main meta has a description, and has for some time, so I'm not sure that's actually working (was [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) just created here?). In any case, the UI bug should definitely be fixed; I'll ask someone about the wiki copying.

Answer (score 3):

Tag wikis can't be edited on per-site metas, AFAIK. The idea is to import them from [the main Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but this isn't happening yet (and it wouldn't be so easy, since tag usage on metas has diverged apart from the mandatory and moderator-only tags).

I see the tag wiki creation button, but clicking it has no effect. You don't even see it because tag wikis require 20k rep to edit unsupervised and [tag edit suggestions don't exist on per-site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites). We're seeing two manifestations of the same UI bug (the UI should clearly say that the tag wiki can't be edited).

Answer (score 2):

I think the SE meta sites ar a special case where only moderators can modify tag wikis. Try improving the tag wikis on the main site instead!

Comment: That might be true - but then the UI is worse! It should either prevent me from even get there (waisting my time), or indicate, that I'm only a visitor, not able to do something.

Comment: @userunknown: Yes there is an interface bug because you shouldn't be shown the edit link to something you aren't even going to be able to suggest an edit for.